# Creating a new rails application in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails

in the previous rails versions you ran

```
rail whatevertheappsname -d mysql
```

what is the new way and how do you generate scaffolds and controllers/migratations ext..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want:

```
rails new whatevertheappsname -d mysql
```

Generation of scaffolds/etc. is like this:

```
rails generate scaffold blah name:string content:text ...
rails generate migration add_field_to_blah ...
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Also, might be worth checking out: http://railscasts.com/. The last few episodes have been dedicated to switching to Rails 3 and are very helpful.

Comment: Definitely, Ryan Bates has a winner in Railscasts. One of the few things I look forward to on Monday mornings.